# VBA cannot get the property of the button you just clicked

Tags: vba, excel

Now I have several buttons in the worksheet, each has set their captions. I want to implement a feature like this: when I clicked the button, a macro is executed to filter a specific row with the caption of itself, so I need to get the property, namely the caption,of the button I just clicked in the inner of the macro.

My pseudo-code like this:

```
Sub filterPM()
    Dim capBt as String
    'get button caption as capBt
    ActiveSheet.Range(...).Autofilter(...,criterial=capBt,...)
End Sub
```

I happened to find one solution is to use `Application.Caller`, but I cannot get the proper caption from it, the object returns the default caption which is like `button134` but not the caption I set when I created the button.

So how can I make this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *alternative text*. Try getting the `Shape` object first by using the name of the shape which is returned by `Application.Caller`. After that you can easily access the alt text of that shape:

```
Sub ButtonClick()
    Dim btn As Shape
    Dim altText As String

    Set btn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes(Application.Caller)

    altText = btn.AlternativeText
    ActiveSheet.Range(...).Autofilter(...,criterial=altText,...)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
capBt = Worksheets("Sheet1").Buttons("Button 1").Text
```

Comment: Unless OP specifically asks for it, ideally we wouldn't offer solutions which use `Select`

Answer (score 0):

Shapes do not have a caption property. You need to access it using the `ActiveSheet.Buttons` objects which has a `.Caption` property.

```
capBt = Sheet1.Buttons(Application.caller).Caption
```

But make sure this macro is only assigned to buttons, not to other types of shapes as well.